# Hot update does not refresh the page

Tags: vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

I have a project in vue3, with quasar framework, using vite for hotupdate and the like, but recently it stopped updating my page after a save, it gives the console [vite] hot updated: , but it doesn't update the page, What can it be?

When checking my npx vite, I see that the port is set to 3000, but my application is using port 9000. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Could you show your code, especially in vite.config.js, vue.config.js, and eventually package.json?